# SSR is short form of Serverside-Rendering

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

I think that [ssr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssr) is short form of Server-Side Rendering as mentioned in [its tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ssr/info), there's another tag: [serverside-rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serverside-rendering) which appears to be about the same thing.

Let's make them synonyms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, the first step was going through and confirming that the [ssr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssr) tag was *only* being used on questions related to server-side rendering.

Just like I feared, that turned out not to be the case. Programmers *love* TLAs, and SSR is also apparently an acronym for [Jetbrains's Structural Search and Replace](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html), as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49773467/how-to-structurally-replace-value-of-one-parameter-of-an-annotation-in-intellij).

Fortunately, it looks like that was the only conflict, and there's already a [structural-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/structural-search) tag, which is more than sufficient.

So this is now complete. I'll keep the synonym mapping [ssr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssr) to [serverside-rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serverside-rendering) for now, but we might want to remove it eventually, if that Jetbrains thingy becomes popular. (I'm pretty happy with unstructured searches, personally.)

Bonus: I renamed the master tag to [server-side-rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/server-side-rendering) because I am like Grammarly for tags.

Comment: "*I renamed the master tag to `server-side-rendering`*" hey, I thought Christmas is still twelve days away, isn't it early for the presents?

Comment: Happy to do what I can, @VLAZ. I think we all deserve a few extra presents this year...

Comment: I'm also agree with renaming both to [tag:server-side-rendersing] ;).